# Why I cannot run Kafka's consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have kafka installed which is working fine as per the link: [Digital Ocean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I want to run the consumer on my browser by hitting: http://localhost:2181

I have checked the error logs of Kafka and of Zookeeper:

Zookeeper(tail -f /var/log/zookeeper/zookeeper.log):

```
2018-05-11 18:52:30,098 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46416 
2018-05-11 18:52:30,098 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46418 
2018-05-11 18:52:30,102 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@362] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error 1195725856 
2018-05-11 18:52:30,103 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46416 (no session established for client) 
2018-05-11 18:52:30,103 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@362] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error 1195725856 
2018-05-11 18:52:30,103 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46418 (no session established for client) 
2018-05-11 18:52:30,104 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46420 
2018-05-11 18:52:30,105 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@362] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error 1195725856 
2018-05-11 18:52:30,106 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46420 (no session established for client)
```

Kafka log:

```
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:132)  
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)  
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:235)  
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:196)     
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:557)  
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:495)    
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:424) 
at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:628)     
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:545)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Note: I am able to run the consumer on my terminal using this command:

```
~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic TutorialTopic --from-beginning
```

Comment: Latest Kafka consumers should not be using Zookeeper

Comment: @cricket_007
Then what should be the changes in my method of starting the kafka?
Can you help me out by pointing which step of the aforementioned Digital Ocean tutorial?

Comment: You would use `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server` and give the Kafka network address... localhost:9092, probably However, I would suggest looking at the Kafka server logs to make sure that it's not having errors

Comment: Also, this tutorial is using a 3+ year old version of Kafka, so I suggest downloading a newer version if you want to learn it. (Confluent has good quick start guides)

Comment: @cricket_007
So, I start with this: `nohup ~/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties > ~/kafka/kafka.log 2>&1 &`

I push a message with this command:
`echo "Hello, World" | ~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic TutorialTopic > /dev/null`

And finally, as per your suggestion, I write this in the terminal :
`~/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --topic TutorialTopic --from-beginning`

Is this right?

Also, looking at the Kafka logs, I did and post the contents in the ques.

Comment: @cricket_007

Can you provide me the link of the confluence or confluent doc? I found multiple. 

Also, should I follow this(https://nodewebapps.com/2017/11/04/getting-started-with-nodejs-and-kafka/) doc?

Comment: 2181 is Zookeeper... You want `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092`. But again, this will only work with Kafka **0.10+**. Otherwise, that looks correct (though, you don't need to echo and pipe into the console producer, once you start that command, you type until you press Ctrl+C). Confluence is a Wiki software. **Confluent** is the enterprise support company (and core developers) behind Kafka. I trust you can search "Confluent Kafka quick start"

Comment: Also, running in DigitalOcean vs some local VM or linux machine isn't any different. So, I would just recommend following official documentation - http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart